# Can I override setValue: forKey:?

Tags: objective-c, key-value-coding

I have an object that is likely to have NSNull set as a value on all of its properties, and I'm working with code that doesn't play nice with NSNull values.  Is it possible to override setValue: forKey: in my object like this?

```
-(void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key {

    if ([value isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        [super setValue:nil forKey:key];
    } else {
        [super setValue:value forKey:key];
    }
}
```

The method doesn't get called when `object.property = [NSNull null]` gets set on it.  How can I make this the default behavior for my setters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are definitely ways to do this. You could declare the relevant properties `@dynamic` and then use `+resolveInstanceMethod:` to actually create the setter on-demand. You can find an example like this in the [sample code for iOS:PTL](https://github.com/iosptl/ios6ptl/blob/master/ch28/Person/Person/Person.m). This example demonstrates how to automatically make your accessors read and write to a dictionary (`properties`) rather than from ivars. To make this work for you, you'd probably need to always store `NSNull` in the dictionary and override the getter (`propertyIMP()`) to convert it to `nil`. So you'd change this:

```
[[self properties] setValue:value forKey:key];
```

to:

```
[[self properties] setValue:(value ?: [NSNull null]) forKey:key];
```

And change:

```
return [[self properties] valueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
```

to:

```
id value = [[self properties] valueForKey:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
return (value == [NSNull null] ? nil : value);
```

Or something like that.

BUT... unless this is a major win, I would avoid this kind of magic. My typical solution to this is to go the other way, and put it on the caller not to pass `[NSNull null]` when they shouldn't. I use a function like `RNNonNull()`:

```
id RNNonNull(id x) { return (x == [NSNull null]) ? nil : x; }
```

Then the caller is responsible for adding the wrapper:

```
obj.foo = RNNonNull(mystuff);
```

If that's not possible, I'd probably override the getters by hand to convert `NSNull` to `nil` rather than doing it with the runtime (it'd be a one-line method). The only reason I'd use the runtime is if there were a bunch of properties, and the object were very simple (purely a data object).

Comment: While useful, I don't think that this actually answered the question regarding -setValue:forKey: overridability.

Answer (score 2):

Setting a property does not actually result in a call to `setValue:forKey:`. You could accomplish this with KVO. For example,

```
@interface Foo
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *bar;
@end

@implementation

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bar" options:0 context:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bar"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (self.bar == [NSNull null]) {
        self.bar = nil;
    }
}
```

So any time the property `bar` is set to `[NSNull null` it will immediately be set to `nil`.

Comment: It will be set to both `NSNull` and `nil`. Any other observers of the same key path will still see `NSNull`.

Comment: They'll see `[NSNull null]` followed by `nil`. The only other way to accomplish the desired behavior would be to set custom setters for all properties of the relevant objects. You could implement the methods such that no observers ever saw `NSNull` as a value, but that's considerably more overhead than the KVO-based solution.